# How vim invokes and executes python interpreter

Tags: vimscript-python, plugin-python-mode

What is happening under the hood when we type `:w !python3` in VIM. Does it invoke the system-wide `python3` or the one present in the virtual environment?

My script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./extnsn/')
```

This appends the `./extnsn/` directory to the `sys.path` variable. However, I am prompted with `module extnsn not found` error.

The error is the same when executing the script with `python-mode` enabled.

Having tough time importing a module from another directory. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your question contain a typo: *...system-wide `python3` **or** the one present...*. Your question is basically incomplete: someone else cannot reproduce your error `module extnsn not found` with the given script. It misses the line `import extnsn` and you could add an empty python module `extnsn` to easily setup a project to reproduce your problem. Also you indicate that you use a virtual environment: however, you missed to describe this and how the situation on the command line is. Tools which help to describe your project layout and env. are `$ tree` and `$ env` showing relevant output.

Comment: Typo corrected @Hotschke. The problem was, the parent directory from which I was executing the script. After setting the correct parent directory with `NERDTree` the issue vanished.